# Is US 2008/0222899 in force?

Tags: us20080222899

In reference to the patent: [US20080222899](https://www.google.com/patents/US20080222899)

Is this patent still enforce

Comment: http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this patent valid? Granted? Which countries does it cover? Are there family members?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m)

Answer (score 1):

This is an application. Per the following, it was abandoned in 2009:
https://register.epo.org/ipfwretrieve?apn=US.68701307.A&lng=en

Answer (score 0):

This is a patent application, not a patent. Thus it isn't yet enforceable. Even if it does become a patent, it is likely the claims would be modified. If you look this application up in the [US Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) website, you can find out that it seems to be abandoned. Thus, it seems unlikely to become a patent.

This [question and answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m) provides more general guidance on researching a patents status so I recommend you review it.