# Prior existing technology patented

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [EP3118774A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP3118774A1)

I am working in the same field, and it seems to me that this patent is similar to a technology already existing since 2001. 
developed by HP: http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/ptm/ . Later developed also by other groups, maybe notably http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/rti/acquisition.php . It has been used specifically on books (https://lichfield.as.uky.edu/st-chad-gospels/rti).

What does this patent means? That no one will be able to use an old technology because someone 15 years later patented it? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The cited document is a patent application. It may or may not become a patent. Even if it does become a patent, its claims may be narrowed or changed based on prior art. It is also important to understand that there may be multiple patentable technologies that address the same field. I'm not in a position to assess the patentability of the application. You may want to review this [question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m) to better understand the patent process.

If you think you have relevant prior art and want to make the European patent office aware of this, there are two procedures, [one prior](http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2016/e/ar115.html) to grant and one [within 9 months](http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2016/e/apv.html) of grant.

As to your last question, to infringe a patent, you must implement every step of at least one claim. It is unlikely that someone using a technology for 15 years prior to a patent being filed will be sued.