# validity of patent and regions covered

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [WO2002019867A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2002019867A1)

Is this patent still valid and if so when does it expire? Does it cover U.S.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this patent valid? Granted? Which countries does it cover? Are there family members?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m)

Comment: The cited document is only an application. I can't find an associated patent, but I'm not an expert at world applications.

Answer (score 2):

The document in question is an international ("PCT") application; it is not a granted patent.
This application was never brought into the US as a national phase application.

There is a time limit of 30 months to bring this application into the US:
https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1842.html

This application, filed in September 2000, is long past that deadline.
In short, this application has not and will not become a granted patent in the US or anywhere else.