# Patent pending for 12 years

Tags: us20060280294

In reference to the patent: [US20060280294](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060280294)

Is this patent granted or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this patent valid? Granted? Which countries does it cover? Are there family members?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [US Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site is you best place to check out the status of a US patent or application. In this case, the latest status as of 3-27-2009 is: "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action". The office action was a non-final rejection. Thus, I believe this application is dead and will never become a patent.

Comment: can you add details related to resurrect if possible. (As you mentioned, it never become a patent)

Comment: @ASHUVERMA  I'm am not a patent attorney or agent so I'm not versed on the laws regarding resurrecting a dead application. If you have such information, feel free to add to my answer or contribute your own.