# Is the patent us4690821 still valid and in force?

Tags: us4690821

Is the patent us4690821 still in force and valid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this patent valid? Granted? Which countries does it cover? Are there family members?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m)

Comment: I haven't looked it up yet because you didn't add a link in your question. However a patent with a number in the 4 millions is very old and certainly expired.

Answer (score 1):

Because this patent issued before 1995, the expiration date should be 17 years from the grant date of 9-01-1987 or 20 years from the earliest filing date, whichever is longer. For patents that issue after 1995, it is generally 20 years from the priority date.

Comment: @ASHUVERMA  Thanks for the edit. This particular patent is so much earlier than 1995 that I was sure it would be 17 years from grant date although your edit is more generally correct.