# Is this patent still active? Was it rejected prior? If so why?

Tags: filing, application, mobile, mobile-phone

In reference to the patent: [US20110299168](https://www.google.com/patents/US20110299168)

Looking to discuss this patent as we have the tech to develop it. Why has it been left under status of application for so long? Has something similar already been granted? Looking to file for something similar. Since this patent was not approved, how can I find out why? Thanks so much!

Comment: https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033 This should answer some of your questions. For the rest of them - do a prior art search and read the docket.

Comment: DonQuiKong's referenced question/answer should provide what you need. Basically you need to look it up in the US Public Pair site.