# Is this still valid?

Tags: validity

In reference to the patent: [WO2000078123A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2000078123A1)

I cant seem to find if this patent is still valid (or been renewed)... Can anyone point me in the direction of the answer? And the source of this information?

Regards,

Bow

Comment: This is an application, not a patent. Patents can't be "renewed".

Comment: https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033 scroll down to "pct"

Comment: Please check out the useful links DonQuiKong provided and if you still have any specific questions, either edit this question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This application seems to have been issued as a patent in the US as [US6543460](https://www.google.com/patents/US6543460). Normally it would expire on June 24, 2019, but it is listed as lapsed so not enforceable. It may be possible to resurrect the patent. There is also an associated patent application [EP1194032A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP1194032A1), which is listed as "withdrawn".