# Is it open patent so that we can use it to our new product

Tags: us20160144214

In reference to the patent: [US20160144214](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160144214A1/en)

Dear Sir/Madam,
I want to develop a new product. Can I use this open patent?
Looking forward  to your advise.

Sincerely,
Hubert

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not communicating with the inventor or assignee of this patent application by posting here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this patent valid? Granted? Which countries does it cover? Are there family members?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m)

Answer (score 1):

As of now this is a pending patent application. Look at [this](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033) question for more information.

This means it does not protect anything right now, **but** if it is granted, it will protect something. That protection applies backwards in time. If you infringe the claims of the future patent (in case it's granted) now, you might have to pay later.

-> No, using it now bears the risk of it becoming a patent in the future. It cannot yet be said what that patent will exactly protect, if anything, because the claims might change during the prosecution (=examination of the patent application).