# Patent has multiple prior art, why is the multiple prior art not preventing the grant of it?

Tags: patentability, prior-art-request, novelty, us8470388

In reference to the patent: [US8470388](https://www.google.com/patents/US8470388)

COUNTRY - Patent Number
United States - 8470388
Australia - 2013207081
Austria - EP2801242
China - CN104115561B
Czech Republic - EP2801242
EPO - EP2801242
France - EP2801242
Germany - 60 2013 011 574.5
Italy - EP2801242
Mexico - MX336165
Netherlands - EP2801242
New Zealand - 628041
Poland - EP2801242
Singapore - 11201403300X
Slovakia - EP2801242
South Africa - 2014/05710
Spain - EP2801242
Sweden - SE2801242
Switzerland - EP2801242
Turkey - 2016-GE-501932
United Kingdom - EP2801242

Normally this patent should be subject to a patentable subject matter, utility, novelty, non-obviousness, and prior disclosure.

It does not carry any added propositions of novelty at all.

This "inventor" has not just derived the invention from someone else, but also used information from abandoned and expired patents that have been abandoned probably due to prior art.

They did not "invent the materials" nor the "methodology for EL lights", nor the EL technology as such.

Prior abandoned and expired patents:
2002: http://www.google.sc/patents/US20030129297 (anybody can use the content of this BASF patent. probably abandoned by BASF due to prior art.)

One of the earliest EL paint adopters (2006) is the Original-XTRA DYNAMICS-Lackschicht prozess.
http://www.xtra-dynamics.com/EL-Beschichtung.html

Prior art that has been copied and translated (2007)https://google.com/patents/WO2007112715A1?cl=en&hl=de (2009)https://google.com/patents/DE102009020191A1?cl=en

Prior art: 
http://web.archive.org/web/20111119171026/http://www.xtra-dynamics.com:80/md.static/faltblatt_xtralight.pdf

Winner of the NoAE innovation contest in 2008:
http://web.archive.org/web/20091106140538/http://www.xtra-dynamics.com:80/winner-of-the-noae-innovation-contest.n3.htm

http://web.archive.org/web/20111114162842/http://www.xtra-dynamics.com:80/el-paint.en.htm

In addition, there is this prior thesis published in 2012:
http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/56133/1/WRAP_THESIS_Middleton_2012.pdf

Comment: how can this been granted? [It hasn't been.](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033)

Comment: Your link clearly states the document is a patent application. Why do you think it has been granted?

Comment: You may want to get worked up about these actually issued patents by the same inventors: https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2801242B1/en, https://patents.google.com/patent/US8470388B1/en

Comment: If somebody wants to add an answer, mention tpos please.

Comment: You could edit the question to ask about preventing the grant of this app.

Comment: I did edit the question with "why is the multiple prior art not preventing the grant of it?"   Prior art that has been copied and translated (2007)[link](https://google.com/patents/WO2007112715A1?cl=en&hl=de)(2009)[link](https://google.com/patents/DE102009020191A1?cl=en)

Comment: Surely the answer is simply that the examiner thought it to be allowable over the prior art they had at hand: can anything more really be said? As such, I'm not sure what the question we could answer is at this stage.

Comment: The links lead to a patent issued in the USA in 2013. Not sure why it is not considered "granted".

Comment: The “grant” is instrumental of infringement of intellectual property rights, breach of contract or of any other right, towards this prior thesis published in 2012.  http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/56133/1/WRAP_THESIS_Middleton_2012.pdf 
The “grant” is instrumental to Plagiarism.
Regarding the examiner thought it to be allowable over the **“prior art they had at hand at that time”** simply has not considered or missed the insights of the full extent available on prior art