# Has GROW Software's patent application (publication number: 20170157859) been granted?

Tags: patent-applications

I'm a journalist who recently reported on this patent from GROW software - patent number: 20170157859. Could I have confirmation that it has been granted? I originally reported it as such and was sent an email to say an application had only been published.

Thanks,

Sam Davies, TCT Magazine

In reference to the patent: [US20170157859](https://www.google.com/patents/US20170157859)

Answer (score 1):

This patent has **not** been granted.

See [here](https://register.epo.org/ipfwretrieve?apn=US.201715432881.A&lng=en) for the dossier of the USPTO.

[Here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033) for more information about patents.

A source for the confusion might be [US9604406 (B2)](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=9604406B2&KC=B2&FT=D&ND=1&date=20170328&DB=&locale=#) which is a granted patent coming from application US2014156053 (A1). The patent you named is a continuation of this (now granted) application (US2014156053). But US20170157859 is still an application.