# What is the status of the patent WO2006064519A2?

Tags: patent-search

In reference to the patent: [WO2006064519A2](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2006064519A2)

What is the status of this patent - whether granted or is under consideration?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this patent valid? Granted? Which countries does it cover? Are there family members?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m)

Answer (score 1):

For the US equivalent patent application [US20090010907A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20090010907A1/en), the current status is: "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action" as of 03-07-2013. I found this information at the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. The European application equivalent is [EP1833966A2](https://www.google.com/patents/EP1833966A2). According to [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadoc?CC=EP&NR=1833966A2&KC=A2&FT=D&ND=&date=20070919&DB=&locale=) that application's status is: "DEEMED TO BE WITHDRAWN" with an effective date of 2014/08/20.

Answer (score -3):

patent ownership has not yet come to an end

Comment: What the heck does this mean? Are you saying it hasn't been granted yet?