# How do vanishing stories on WhatsApp not infringe Snapchats patents?

Tags: patent-infringement, facebook, infringment

Looking at Snapchat's patent [Ephemeral message galleries](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9537811B2/en) it would seem, at least superficially, that vanishing status updates on WhatsApp do exactly what this patent protects. I copy the relevant portion of the first claim below:

> 1. A server, comprising:
>
>    a processor; and
>
>    a memory storing instructions executed by the processor to:
>      maintain an ephemeral gallery comprising a plurality of ephemeral messages posted by a user for viewing by one or more recipients, wherein each of the ephemeral messages comprises a photograph or a video, the maintaining of the ephemeral gallery comprising making the ephemeral gallery available for viewing, upon request, via respective user devices associated with the one or more recipients;
>
>    for each of the plurality of ephemeral messages,
>      maintain an associated message duration parameter that indicates a display duration for the corresponding ephemeral message during viewing of the ephemeral gallery, and
>
>    maintain a gallery participation parameter that indicates a time value for continued availability of the corresponding ephemeral message in the ephemeral gallery;
>
>    responsive to receiving an ephemeral gallery view request from one of the one or more recipients, cause automated sequential display of the plurality of ephemeral messages on a corresponding user device by performance of operations comprising:
>
>    starting a message timer when viewing of one of the plurality of the ephemeral messages is commenced,
>
>    determining that the message timer expires when the message timer equals the corresponding display duration,
>
>    responsive to expiry of the message timer, displaying a next one of the plurality of ephemeral messages in the ephemeral gallery, and
>      repeating the starting, determining, and displaying operations until all ephemeral messages in the ephemeral gallery are viewed;
>
>    remove a particular one of the plurality ephemeral messages from the ephemeral gallery in response to the identification of an expired gallery participation parameter corresponding to the particular ephemeral message, the particular ephemeral message after removal thereof being unavailable for recipient viewing as part of the ephemeral gallery; and
>
>    eliminate the ephemeral gallery so that the ephemeral gallery is unavailable for viewing responsive to any recipient request, the ephemeral gallery being eliminated upon expiration of either a gallery timer or upon expiration of the gallery participation parameter of a last message in the ephemeral gallery, the last message being that one of the plurality of ephemeral messages which was posted to the ephemeral gallery last.

From what I see on WhatsApp, they effectively do all of it.

Do they actually not (and my reading of the patent is erroneous) or could there be other reasons Snapchat is okay having its patents infringed by the same entity that seems well poised to crush it?

Comment: Do you have a specific WhatsApp patent you can reference?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstand you. The question is asking about WhatsApp infringing Snapchat patents.

Comment: Either way, what specific patents are you referring too. If you want help, at least don't make everyone have to do patent searches.

Comment: I'm not. The patent is already linked to in the first sentence...

Comment: Thanks, that is an application. I fixed your link to the actual granted patent. Claims are what is important and the granted patents usually has narrower claims than the application.

Comment: I edited in the granted claim from the US application. See here for information about the difference between (PCT) applications (what you linked) and granted patents (what eric linked): https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033

Comment: Can you edit your question using the claim from the actual granted patent? Also, you must quote all of the claim! To infringe every step of a claim must be infringed upon, not just a portion.

Comment: @EricShain gotcha, faster ;)

Comment: @DonQuiKong  I was still drinking my morning coffee...

Comment: I don't use Snapchat or WhatsApp, so I might have to sit this one out.

Comment: @EricShain right. Many thanks for that. I'd been following what google popped up when I looked for the patent without looking at if it's an application or grant.

Comment: @EricShain no problemo. I'm gonna answer it myself probably. Already figured it out from the granted patent. It's really really narrowed down the claim.

Comment: @DonQuiKong thanks a lot for looking up the actually granted patent. And that other answer detailing the differences. I'm gonna remember to double check what google spits out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first pardon my impertinence to answer my own question in an area where my knowledge is only cursory.

The patent application of Snapchat was what might be construed as overly broad and most, if not all, of the functionality of WhatsApp's feature of ephemeral status updates infringe upon it.

But the actually granted patent significantly narrowed those claims down to the very specific implementation of Snapchat stories. In particular:

> ... responsive to receiving an ephemeral gallery view request from one of
>   the one or more recipients, cause automated sequential display of the
>   plurality of ephemeral ...

WhatsApp doesn't automatically display the messages sequentially. The user has to manually select each for viewing. So, no infringement.

Of course this does raise the interesting concern of 1) whether the patent office(r) checked out the Snapchat app, understood what it was all about, then narrowed the patent claims down to that particular implementation. And 2) if Snapchat hadn't actually implemented it, might they have been granted the patent they'd applied for, I.e the ephemeral messages format in general. Since there'd have been no implementation, the whole ephemerality business could have been considered a specific implementation of mobile messages, rather than its own generic format.

Comment: That's probably a patent for the snapchat stories. In my opinion, learning and answering ones own question is no impertinence.

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, so long as it isn't just a ploy to bump your reputation. If I were more social media savvy I might have tried answering, but I'm too old...

Comment: @DonQuiKong yes and that's the key bit of difference/learning as I now realize: the granted patent is for Snapchat stories, or something very close. But the patent application was for almost the entire general format of ephemeral messages.

Comment: Imho you should accept this answer, I don't think there's another one coming soon ;)

Comment: So I did. One isn't allowed to accept one's own answer until a couple of days have elapsed. This policy probably has to do with the point raised by @EricShain about it being a ploy to boost one's reputation.

Comment: @EricShain more impertinence coming up: imho, no one's too old until they're dead. And I can tell you're very much alive. While I cant reasonably recommend you actually become an active user of either service (they don't actually add tremendous new value; for most people it's more about their friends being on it), it might not be a bad idea to see what they're all about - might take a while to get the hang of it but it's always good to see/learn new things, no?

Comment: @Yogesch I was being facetious. In any case, most social media just doesn't work for me personally other than LinkedIn and Stack Exchange.