# Is it possible to write software that doesn't infringe on patents?

Tags: patent-infringement, software, non-obviousness, business-methods, uber

I'm working on app not similar to Uber, but one that also facilitates peer-to-peer economic activity. However, I recently came across [a patent filed by Uber](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130132246), entitled

> "**Providing a summary or receipt for on-demand services through use of portable computing devices**"

Here is the abstract:

> **ABSTRACT**
>
> A method for providing a service summary or receipt on a
> computing device is provided. One or more processors determine
> information for a service rendered for a user. The information
> includes a cost for the service, a type of service performed, and a
> person who performed the service. A summary receipt panel is provided
> on a display of the computing device and includes the information for
> the service rendered. The one or more processors provide, on the
> summary receipt panel, a map that identifies a location relevant to
> the service rendered and a feedback feature that enables the user to
> rate the service received.

I'm baffled that this could even be patented at all. Regardless, how can I ensure that the receipts in my app do not infringe on this [ridiculous] patent? Is it enough to not use a map in the receipt, or to not include the feedback widget, etc?

On a more general note, and the title of this question - **is it at all possible to avoid software patent infringement? ** By now it would seem everything you can think of is patented.

Comment: Don't worry about the abstract. Just focus on the claims.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a patent, that's a patent application. Which means, it doesn't protect anything yet and might never. See [this question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033) for more information.

Furthermore, the abstract and description of a patent can contain **anything**. The protection of a patent is defined by the claims. The independent claims of the patent application currently read as follows below, however they are subject to change (read: narrowing) during the prosecution, so this might not be the final form. It is normal to have very broad claims in the application - but those have not yet been found patentable by the patent office - I can go and claim the world, doesn't mean anyone will give it to me.

Independent claim 1

> 1. A method for providing a service summary or receipt on a computing device, the method being performed by one or more processors and comprising:
>      determining information for a service rendered for a user, the information including a cost for the service, a type of service performed, and a person who performed the service;
>      providing a summary receipt panel on a display of the computing device that includes the information for the service rendered;
>      providing, on the summary receipt panel, a map that identifies a location relevant to the service rendered; and
>      providing, on the summary receipt panel, a feedback feature that enables the user to rate the service received.

Independent claim 8

> 8. A non-transitory computer-readable medium storing instructions that, when executed by one or more processors, causes the one or more processors to perform steps comprising:
>      determining information for a service rendered for a user, the information including a cost for the service, a type of service performed, and a person who performed the service;
>      providing a summary receipt panel on a display of the computing device that includes the information for the service rendered;
>      providing, on the summary receipt panel, a map that identifies a location relevant to the service rendered; and
>      providing, on the summary receipt panel, a feedback feature that enables the user to rate the service received.

Independent claim 15

> 15. A mobile computing device comprising:
>       a display;
>       one or more memory resources; and
>       one or more processors coupled to the display and the one or more memory resources, the one or more processors to:
>       determine information for a service rendered for a user, the information including a cost for the service, a type of service performed, and a person who performed the service;
>       provide a summary receipt panel on a display of the computing device that includes the information for the service rendered;
>       provide, on the summary receipt panel, a map that identifies a location relevant to the service rendered; and
>       provide, on the summary receipt panel, a feedback feature that enables the user to rate the service received.

Comment: Really good answer with one missing bit. You should emphasize that to infringe on a patent you have to implement every step of at least one claim. A lot of people think each step in a claim is separately protected.

Comment: @EricShain do you have a source for that ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein  Not off hand, but it is a basic principle of infringement.

Comment: @EricShain if you are correct, then perhaps my question should have been "is it possible to obtain a software patent that protects you?" since with software it is easy to change some minor details and avoid infringing on a patent.

Comment: @CodyBugstein A computer program, as a whole, isn't patentable. An algorithm used to solve a specific need may be. Good claims are written to avoid being circumvented by trivial differences.

Comment: @EricShain It appears that most software patents (including the one referenced in my original question) are not algorithms, but rather general ideas about a use case for software (i.e. in this case, to compile and display a receipt for a service)