# If someone owns a patent, does this mean they some sort of rights from places that use their invention?

Tags: patent-infringement, copyright

https://www.google.lk/patents/WO2000073955A9?dq=ininventor:%22Michael+F.+Guheen%22&cl=en

I happened on this and started wondering why this guy doesn't own half the Internet because shopping carts are pretty ubiquitous.  What does the patent give this person here?

> > Methods, concepts and technology for a virtual shopping system capable
> >     of assessing needs of a customer and recommending a product or service
> >     based on such assessed needs
>
> WO 2000073955 A9
>
> ABSTRACT  translated
>
> > from French The present invention relates to a system for performing
> >     virtual business transactions after identifying the needs of the user.
> >     Firstly, the system assesses the needs of a user. It then generates,
> >     based on the user's needs, a solution, which is displayed. Payment is
> >     then accepted in exchange for the solution. It should be noted that in
> >     the present specification of the invention, the solution is, but not
> >     limited to, a product or a service.

Comment: This question: https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17115/18033 should answer why this "patent" (spoiler: it wasn't granted) doesn't own the internet. You might want to refine your question after that.

Comment: Also, the abstract is possibly the least informative part of a patent.