# How does MSR Reactor camp stove not infringe on this patent?

Tags: us20140311475

In reference to the patent: [US20140311475](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20140311475A1/en)

The MSR Reactor stove is "Patent Pending", so I am curious to know how they are able to sell a device nearly identical to Jetboil's design? How are they not infringing on the existing patent?

https://www.msrgear.com/stoves/reactor-stove-systems-10

Comment: The "patent" you cite is only an application. Thus it is not an "existing patent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

US20140311475 is not an existing patent. It is a patent application. If you are unclear about the distinction, you may want to review this [question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m). We don't know what the status is of the MSR Reactor stove patent application since you don't list it. It may very well predate US20140311475. Looking at the file wrapper in the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair), US20140311475 has received a Final Rejection which has been appealed. I'm not an attorney, but at this point, US20140311475 is not a patent and could very likely never become a patent.

Additional, other than a visual similarity between the MSR Reactor stove and the figures in US20140311475, you have no way to understand whether it actually would have infringed on the resulting patent from US20140311475 without knowing its specific technical details compared to the claims. Claims in applications are very often far broader than what eventually gets granted in patents. Camp stoves have existed for many years, so US20140311475 could not be patenting camp stoves in general. It would have to be trying to patent a very specific implementation.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in my response. I was offline for a few days. 

I appreciate all the effort you put into the response. Was very helpful!