# is this expired now? open for using freely?

Tags: patent-lifetime

In reference to the patent: [US5803725](https://www.google.com/patents/US5803725)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this patent valid? Granted? Which countries does it cover? Are there family members?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m)

Comment: https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/13056/18033

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filing, CIP, Con, PCT, Priority, etc and Expiration Date](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/13056/filing-cip-con-pct-priority-etc-and-expiration-date)

Answer (score 0):

The patent's priority date is June 13th, 1997 so it should expire 20 years later on June 13th, 2017.